# NameError while calling a function inside a loop

Tags: python, visual-studio, function, loops

I'm currently a new developer in python, and I'm trying to make a simple backpropagation ANN from a code that I found in the internet to work with the space invaders game.

I'm using Visual Studio Code 2015 just to debug, so I can understand how the code flows.

I have a file named spaceinvaders.py, and inside this file all the code was writen with a lot of classes that create sprites, sounds and all of the other game stuff.

To implement the ANN, I just pasted the code and try to run it, but whenever I try to make a call from 2 specific functions, I get the "NameError was unhandled by the user code - global name "**activate_neuron**" is not defined", but the function is **already defined**!

I searched a lot looking for a similar problem, but got no ideias how to solve it (mostly because I'm a newer developing on Python).

Here's the full code, and the error when I call the function "**activate_neuron**" inside the function "**forward_propagate**".

```
[Other Space Invaders Classes]
    class BackPropagation (object):

        def inicializar_rede_neural(n_inputs, n_hidden, n_outputs):
            network = list()
            #inicializa os pesos da input para a hidden layer
            hidden_layer = [{'weights':[random() for i in range(n_inputs + 1)]} for i in range(n_hidden)]
            network.append(hidden_layer)
            #inicializa os pesos da hidden para a output layer
            output_layer = [{'weights':[random() for i in range(n_hidden + 1)]} for i in range(n_outputs)]
            network.append(output_layer)
            return network

        #Faz a ativação do neurônio
        def activate_neuron(weights, inputs):
            activation = weights[-1]
            for i in range(len(weights)-1):
                activation += weights[i] * inputs[i]
            return activation

        # Transfer neuron activation (função sigmoide)
        def transferir(activation):
            return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-activation))

        # Realiza o foward propagate
        def forward_propagate(network, row):
            inputs = row
            for layer in network:
                new_inputs = []
                for neuron in layer:
                    activation = activate_neuron(neuron['weights'], inputs) >Here's the error<
                    neuron['output'] = transferir(activation)
                    new_inputs.append(neuron['output'])
                inputs = new_inputs
            return inputs

        np.random.seed(1)
        network = inicializar_rede_neural(3, 2, 1)
        for layer in network:
            print(layer)
        row = [1, 1, 0, None]
        output = forward_propagate(network, row)
        print(output)
```

Also I think that I'm going to get the same error type trying to call the next function called "**transferir**".

You guys have any idea to solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Your function is defined in scope of `BackPropagation` class, so, since you don't use `self` in arguments - you should call it like `BackPropagation.activate_neuron`. Also, read [this](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/) to get better understanding of python classes

Comment: `activate_neuron` is a method, you are required to access it through the instance, e.g. `self.activate_neuron(...)` Python != Java. Note, your class definition has all sorts of problems. I suggest reading a tutorial on OOP in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to python, then I can understand why you missed this. The code needs to be

```
activation = self.activate_neuron(neuron['weights'], inputs)
```

not

```
activation = activate_neuron(neuron['weights'], inputs)
```

whenever calling a function created within the same class, you need to use self.function() instead of just function(). This quirk is mostly just for python, but you'll see it a lot

Edit: Entire class redone

```
[Other Space Invaders Classes]
    class BackPropagation(object):

        def inicializar_rede_neural(self, n_inputs, n_hidden, n_outputs):
            network = []
            #inicializa os pesos da input para a hidden layer
            hidden_layer = [{'weights':[random() for i in range(n_inputs + 1)]} for i in range(n_hidden)]
            network.append(hidden_layer)
            #inicializa os pesos da hidden para a output layer
            output_layer = [{'weights':[random() for i in range(n_hidden + 1)]} for i in range(n_outputs)]
            network.append(output_layer)
            return network

        #Faz a ativação do neurônio
        def activate_neuron(self, weights, inputs):
            activation = weights[-1]
            for i in range(len(weights)-1):
                activation += weights[i] * inputs[i]
            return activation

        # Transfer neuron activation (self, função sigmoide)
        def transferir(self, activation):
            return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-activation))

        # Realiza o foward propagate
        def forward_propagate(self, network, row):
            inputs = row
            for layer in network:
                new_inputs = []
                for neuron in layer:
                    activation = self.activate_neuron(neuron['weights'], inputs) #>Here's the error<
                    neuron['output'] = self.transferir(activation)
                    new_inputs.append(neuron['output'])
                inputs = new_inputs
            return inputs

    np.random.seed(1)
    backprop = BackPropagation()
    network = backprop.inicializar_rede_neural(3, 2, 1)
    for layer in network:
        print(layer)
    row = [1, 1, 0, None]
    output = backprop.forward_propagate(network, row)
    print(output)
```

Comment: This is not quite true. `self` is needed only when referring to methods that rely on instance variables. `Class.method()` - will also work with static and class methods

Comment: @Yaroslav I personally like to use self because it's consistent in my head

Comment: @Yardid Thanks for the reply bud! But self.function doesn't work :(

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov Thanks for the reaply bud! But for some reason, Class.method also doesn't worked :( Now I got the error "Class not defined".
If I just copy the entire code from the class, the code works. But trying to call the function from this way (with a lot of classes, and the function inside the class) doesn't work.

Comment: I just noticed that your code has some problems elsewhere, so I'll copy and paste to fix those

Comment: @Yardid Thanks again for the reply bud, but it still doesn't work :( In the line "backprop = BackPropagation()", I got the error "BackPropagation is not defined", same as the other errors :<

Comment: Is that line nested within the class? It should be called outside the class definition

Comment: @Yardid IT WORKED! Thank you so much for your help bud! I think I got the ideia, basically I need to put all the logic on the class, and then make the calls to the functions outside the class. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. If you could mark this answer as correct that would be awesome, thanks.